# How to convert from a set to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, set, python-itertools

The question:

I need to convert a set to an array. If I try to just do np.array(X), I get an array that contains a set, which isn't very helpful. If I convert my set to a list and then my list to an array, everything works fine, but that seems needlessly complex (the line of code in question is a convoluted mess of needless complexity already).  Is there a way to go straight from set to array?

---

Code context, if helpful:

```
rad = 0.944
n = 5
pairs = np.array(list(set(chain.from_iterable(((x,y),(x,-y),(-x,y),(-x,-y)) for x in np.linspace(0, rad, n) for y in np.linspace(0, rad, n) if math.hypot(x,y) <= rad))))
```

The point of the set is to remove duplicates from the chain.  I know there are ways of doing this with an array, but it doesn't seem possible to convert an itertools.chain object directly into an array either.

Holistically, this code just models a circle using a uniform distribution of x,y points, and speeds up the process by evoking symmetry between the four quadrants.

Comment: So the `set` is really just there to remove a couple of duplicate `(0, 0)` points?

Comment: There will be four duplicate (0,0) points, but also two duplicates of each point along the lines where the quadrants meet (anywhere where one of x or y is zero).

Comment: @threnna The answer is no, but your code isn't going to be any less convoluted just because you remove the call to `list`.

Comment: Thanks @Goyo.  I rewrote it to be less convoluted using the itertools.product function; the increase to efficiency is negligible, but I think the readability is much improved.

`pairs = np.array([item for item in product(np.linspace(-rad, rad, 2*n-1), repeat=2) if hypot(item[0], item[1]) <= rad])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion is that there is no easier way to convert a set to an array other than going through a list first.

In terms of my particular situation, I ended up using the following:

```
rad = 0.944
n = 5
pairs = np.array([item for item in itertools.product(np.linspace(-rad, rad, 2*n-1), repeat=2) if math.hypot(item[0], item[1]) <= rad])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure Numpythonic approach:

```
In [244]: lins = np.unique(np.linspace(0, rad, n))
# Create the prucuct of lins
In [245]: arr = np.array((np.repeat(lins, 5), np.tile(lins, 5))).T
# remove extra items based on your condition
In [246]: new = np.compress(np.sqrt(np.power(arr, 2).sum(1)) <= 0.944, arr, 0)

In [247]: a = np.array([ 1, -1])
# Create a product of (-1, 1) for creating the total expected result by multiplying the product on each row of the compressed array
In [248]: perm = np.array((np.repeat(a, 2), np.tile(a, 2))).T

In [249]: total = new[:,None] * perm
```

Note that if you make sure that there is no duplicate item in your `linspace` array there won't be any one in the total combinations.

And here is the `total` result:

```
array([[[ 0.   ,  0.   ],
        [ 0.   , -0.   ],
        [-0.   ,  0.   ],
        [-0.   , -0.   ]],

       [[ 0.   ,  0.236],
        [ 0.   , -0.236],
        [-0.   ,  0.236],
        [-0.   , -0.236]],

       [[ 0.   ,  0.472],
        [ 0.   , -0.472],
        [-0.   ,  0.472],
        [-0.   , -0.472]],

       [[ 0.   ,  0.708],
        [ 0.   , -0.708],
        [-0.   ,  0.708],
        [-0.   , -0.708]],

       [[ 0.   ,  0.944],
        [ 0.   , -0.944],
        [-0.   ,  0.944],
        [-0.   , -0.944]],

       [[ 0.236,  0.   ],
        [ 0.236, -0.   ],
        [-0.236,  0.   ],
        [-0.236, -0.   ]],

       [[ 0.236,  0.236],
        [ 0.236, -0.236],
        [-0.236,  0.236],
        [-0.236, -0.236]],

       [[ 0.236,  0.472],
        [ 0.236, -0.472],
        [-0.236,  0.472],
        [-0.236, -0.472]],

       [[ 0.236,  0.708],
        [ 0.236, -0.708],
        [-0.236,  0.708],
        [-0.236, -0.708]],

       [[ 0.472,  0.   ],
        [ 0.472, -0.   ],
        [-0.472,  0.   ],
        [-0.472, -0.   ]],

       [[ 0.472,  0.236],
        [ 0.472, -0.236],
        [-0.472,  0.236],
        [-0.472, -0.236]],

       [[ 0.472,  0.472],
        [ 0.472, -0.472],
        [-0.472,  0.472],
        [-0.472, -0.472]],

       [[ 0.472,  0.708],
        [ 0.472, -0.708],
        [-0.472,  0.708],
        [-0.472, -0.708]],

       [[ 0.708,  0.   ],
        [ 0.708, -0.   ],
        [-0.708,  0.   ],
        [-0.708, -0.   ]],

       [[ 0.708,  0.236],
        [ 0.708, -0.236],
        [-0.708,  0.236],
        [-0.708, -0.236]],

       [[ 0.708,  0.472],
        [ 0.708, -0.472],
        [-0.708,  0.472],
        [-0.708, -0.472]],

       [[ 0.944,  0.   ],
        [ 0.944, -0.   ],
        [-0.944,  0.   ],
        [-0.944, -0.   ]]])
```

Comment: This output is just np.linspace(-rad, rad, n*2), not a list of the tuple combinations.

Comment: This doesn't remove any of the duplicates -- (0.944, 0) and (0.944, -0) are the same point, for example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `np.fromiter` to construct an array directly from the generator output of `chain.from_iterable`, and `np.unique` to remove duplicates:

```
pairs = np.unique(np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data), dtype=float))
```

Note that the `dtype` argument of the `np.fromiter` function is required.

Comment: I tried this, but since my data is tuples, I get ValueError: cannot create object arrays from iterator